# Mudança de idioma em site PHP de acordo com link

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo um site em PHP em três idiomas.
Tenho inclusive uma função changeLang(lang) que muda perfeitamente o idioma de português pra inglês ou espanhol.
Contudo, o link da minha página sempre fica o mesmo, mesmo quando eu mudo o idioma:

```
http://www.minhapagina.com/phase01?lang=pt-br
```

Queria ter a opção de poder mudar o idioma pra inglês (eng) ou espanhol (esp) quando eu mudo no link também. Tentei algo assim no início da página phase01.php, mas não deu certo:

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    if($_GET['lang'] == 'eng'){
        echo "<script>window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { changeLang(1); }, false);</script>";
    }
    elseif($_GET['lang'] == 'esp'){
        echo "<script>window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { changeLang(2); }, false);</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { changeLang(0); }, false);</script>";
    }
}
```

O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Use um evento onclick para mudar o idioma sem precisar passar a referencia em cada link.

Comment: No caso, o changeLang já é um evento que eu tenho onClick no meu site (tem a opção de idiomas no header da página) e funciona bem. Só que mesmo com a mudança de idioma o link não muda, ficando sempre lang=pt-br. Na verdade, eu assumi esse site de um outro desenvolvedor, então estou tendo que correr atrás de várias coisas nele.

Comment: Mostre a forma como você está criando os links.